# Java 1.8: any way to O(1) an object in a LinkedList<> with remove( object )?

Tags: java, linked-list

I think not, so what I've done is to manually write a double-linked list mapping iOrderID to Order, and support it with a HashMap.  I use the HashMap to find the order, and when I do, I can de-link it instantly.

```
class Order {
    Product product;
    Order orderPrev, orderNext;

    // The business fields I need are here.
}

Map<Integer, Order> maporder = new HashMap<>();
```

Then to delete:

```
void Delete( int iOrderID ) {
    Order order = maporder.get( iOrderID );

    if ( order == null ) {
        LogError( "order not found" );
        return false;
    }

    maporder.remove( order.iOrderID );

    if ( orderPrev != null ) {
        orderPrev.orderNext = orderNext;
    } else {
        product.orderHead = orderNext;
    }

    if ( orderNext != null ) {
        orderNext.orderPrev = orderPrev;
    } else {
        product.orderTail = orderPrev;
    }
```

(Note that like the top 20 pages you find on Google that summarize O() for various options report `remove()` as O(1) but I'm positive they're all talking about `removeFirst()` and maybe `removeLast()`.)

Comment: Linked lists don't support `O(1)` removal as you'd _have_ to look up the element/node to remove - so some other means to look it up like what you've done would be necessary. However, wouldn't `LinkedHashMap` already provide this for you?

Comment: I don't understand where you get `orderNext` and `orderPrev` from.

Comment: One approach might be: Mark the elements as removed (put their IDs into some `Set` or similar), and remove them lazily the next time you encounter them e.g. when you iterate the list. This should be effectively O(1).

Comment: I think you could be better off by using a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: OK, stubbed out the orderNext, orderPrev, level variables.

Comment: @AlexRolea I'll look into it.